# How do I create a histogram from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram, cpu-word, frequency-distribution

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

What is the best way to plot the word frequencies? I wanted to plot a histogram of the frequencies, it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to get a histogram from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `plot.bar`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('words').plot.bar(rot=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: @Laily. Please can you check my answer if this solves your problem before I remove my post except if you accept the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks - you solved my problem. Just one more question would I be able to use plt.hist() at all here? @Corralien

Comment: An histogram is not the same thing as a bar plot. Try: `plt.hist(df['frequencies'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to get is:

```
df.plot(x='words',y='frequencies',kind='bar')
```